# Convert Dictionary<int, int?> to Dictionary<int, int> by skipping null values with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, nullable

I have the following `Product` class:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }     
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have to count how many `Product` I have for each `CategoryId` and place them in a `Dictionary<int, int>`. Therefore:

```
IQueryable<Product> products = _productServices.GetAll(); //return IQueryable<Product>

Dictionary<int, int> productDict =  products.ToList()
                                            .GroupBy(p => p.CategoryId)
                                            .ToDictionary(pgroup => pgroup.key, pgroup => pgroup.Count());
```

The problem is that I obtain a `Dictionary<int?, int>` from the `ToDictionary()`. Even if I pre-filter the null values by placing `Where(p => p.CategoryId != null)` I do not change the type of `CategoryId` to `int`. I also tried to create and anonymous type:

```
products.ToList()
        .GroupBy(p => p.CategoryId)
        .Select(p => new { p.key ?? -1, p.Count() }  
        .ToDictionary(pgroup => pgroup.key, pgroup => pgroup);
```

But it gives an `Invalid anonymous type member declarator` error. I also tried to remove the `ToList()` but no luck. I google it a bit and I haven't found anybody having this issue, although I think this situation might be frequent, especially when working with **EF** and **databases**. Anybody has a solution?

Comment: Try `p.CategoryId.Value` (which is non-nullable) instead of `p.CategoryId`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `CategoryId` is a nullable. So you need to select it's [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) property first:

```
products.ToList()
        .Where(p => p.CategoryId.HasValue)
        .Select(p => p.CategoryId.Value)
        .GroupBy(i => i)
        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: +1 for including *why* it doesn't work, not simply working around it.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use

```
products.ToList()
    .GroupBy(p => p.CategoryId)
    .Where(pgroup => pgroup.Key.HasValue)
    .ToDictionary(pgroup => pgroup.Key.Value, pgroup => pgroup.Count());
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
.ToDictionary(pgroup => pgroup.Key ?? -1, pgroup => pgroup.Count());
```

And regarding your syntax error with the anonymous type, the correct syntax is as follows:

```
.Select(p => new { Key = p.Key ?? -1, Count = p.Count() })
```

Comment: minor point; the op does explicitly say "skipping null values" - trying to include them is great, but you'd need to ask whether `-1` is already a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the null values, and then use the `.Value` property of the `int?` as the grouping key:

```
products.ToList()
        .Where(p => p.CategoryId.HasValue)
        .GroupBy(p => p.CategoryId.Value)
        .ToDictionary(pgroup => pgroup.key, pgroup => pgroup.Count());
```